# Modificar datos de cabecera y cookies en petición CURL

Tags: nodejs, http, curl

Muy buenas,

Estoy utilizando Node (7.7.4) y la librería curl para juguetear un poco con las peticiones HTTP y aprender un poco de web crawling. La propia librería indica cómo hacer una simple petición GET:

```
curl.get(url, options, function(err, response, body) {});
```

Simple, vale. He probado a hacer una petición con los "options" a null para ver qué tal, y efectivamente realiza la petición.

Ahora la cosa, es que quiero modificar las cabeceras de la petición, poner una cookie propia y así, para hacer ciertas pruebas en redes sociales. Por ejemplo, si hago un CURL a mi Instagram, me devuelve la página de login, ya que no está puesta la cookie con los datos de sesión en el CURL, sino en mi navegador. Siendo así, me gustaría ver cómo puedo meter mi cookie en la petición, y qué otros datos debería cambiar de los headers HTTP, para que el servidor de Instagram tome el CURL como si fuera una petición normal desde el navegador, estando logueado.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacer esto?

¡Saludos!

Comment: En [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/curl) salen tropecientos paquetes `curl` ¿ El que has elegido (que no lo dices) es el único sin documentación ?

Comment: @Trauma Sí, justamente es el que no tiene nada de documentación, "curl" a secas... ¿Sabes de alguno más completito?

Comment: node_fetch. Ese es mi paquete favorito de la última semana

Comment: +1  a [node-fetch](https://npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). Tiene la ventaja de ser una implementación del estándar, puedes usar el mismo código tanto en Node.js como en el navegador. Otra opción muy usada es [request](https://npmjs.com/package/request).